# padding the binary representation of a BigInteger

Tags: java

Just wondering how / if it is possible to pad a string to the left. I saw to use format() but i didnt know what to put in the paramters for my case.

Im starting originally with a BigInteger `Message` then saying `message.toString(2)` to make the binary representation of the BigInteger as the string. But in this case I want to check if the length is a multiple of 8, and if it is not pad the string to the length of the next multiple of 8.

So in my case after i do `message.toString(2)` the length of that string im calling `plaintext` is 63, so I want to left pad it to length 64 by adding a zero at the front.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can calculate the number of zeros that you want to add to the left like this:

```
int numZeros = 8 - str.length() % 8;
```

If `numZeros` is not 8, you can pad the string like this:

```
if (str.length() % 8 != 0) {
    str = "00000000".substring(str.length() % 8) + str;
}
```

Here is a [demo on ideone](http://ideone.com/PVVFp8).